# FB-Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am implementing Facebook feed functionality in my website using 'FB-like-box' I was able to replicate it similar to that shown in Facebook developer site.

But when I again started testing the code(no change has been done) today I am getting additional link in the like box and I am not able to get rid of it.

You can see the additional links 'Like Page', 'Boom Post' in the screenshot. Can some one please advice me how to get rid of the additional links. Please find the code below.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

 <script>
  (function(d, s, id) {

    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

   js.src =      "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=515052318562357&version=2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div class="fb-container">

 <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/NayaCompLtd" data-width="300"    data-ajax="false" height="360" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of them? I'm pretty sure you are the only one seeing them

Comment: You're seeing that "Boost Post" button because you're the admin of the page, that's it

Comment: @Adam: I am seeing that link even with someone else app_id for which I am not the admin

Comment: @Wizkid: This behavior is happening recently earlier there was no such links as 'Boom Post', 'Like', Comment', 'Share', The problem is I didn't change a bit in the code but suddenly its appearing altogether differently.

Comment: Who did mention anything about "app_id"? we're talking about the page :) create a jsFiddle and I will screenshot it for you

Comment: @AdamAzad: Here yiu go check out the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/wv232/ Pleas log onto facebook to get the feeds

Comment: Happy? http://prntscr.com/3orl5i

Comment: @AdamAzad: Thanks, But the problem is still there I still see the other links like 'Like Page', 'like', 'share', . Is there a way to hide them? Actually just two days back it was appearing completely different, Please check out the link http://prntscr.com/3os3ns Is there a way that I can get my feeds appear like the way they were appearing before.

Answer (score 0):

The Like Button is there because it´s a major element of the Like Box.

The "Boost Post" Button is only visible for you, and i highly doubt that you can remove it either.